# VirtualBox can't open Windows 7

Tags: virtualbox, windows-7

I downloaded a Windows 7 iso, created the VM for it, and it won't open. I get the following error box:

Failed to open a session for the virtual machine VeenDoze.

The virtual machine 'VeenDoze' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: MachineWrap
Interface: IMachine {f30138d4-e5ea-4b3a-8858-a059de4c93fd}

And if that weren't annoying enough, I can't get rid of Virtual Box. I've tried uninstalling through terminal and software center and it won't go away.

Running Ubuntu 15.04 Unity

Comment: Which version of Virtualbox are you using?

Comment: I googled your error. It seems a similar issue existed in beta version of VBox 5, and it was fixed in final stable release. Please upgrade to the latest and then try.

Comment: I'm using 5.0.2. As far as I know, it's the latest version. I've tried removing it so I can try a different version or different software, but I can't remove it from my system.

Answer (score 2):

Seen the same issue, fixed it by running:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

After this the VM was able to boot.

Comment: Running Ubuntu 16.04 - `sudo: /etc/init.d/vboxdrv: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

Running Ubuntu 16.04, you'll have to run this script if you update the kernel

```
sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup
```